# Forking a repository on github

Tags: git, github

I have permissions to private Github repository under employer's Github account for my personal github login.  I forked the repository so I could work on it in my personal github account, and then commit there.  Everything works as expected, but when someone commits and pushes to the employer's private github repository it doesn't show up in my forked github repository.  There is no merge option from the source to the forked repo.  How do people keep this in sync??

Answer (score 4):

GitHub forks don't synchronize automatically. You have to merge changes to your personal repository and then push them to your repository and GitHub.

Comment: How do you merge backwards?  I can merge from the forked repository into the parent, but there is not an option to do it the other way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have write permission to your employer's repo you can push the changes there as well; otherwise you need to persuade the upstream repository owner to merge your changes.  GitHub has a mechanism for this, called [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

Answer (score 2):

When you fork a repository, it creates a duplicated repository to which you can push changes. However, it is independent of the original repository, so it does not automatically update itself. If you want to grab the latest changes from your employer's repository, you will first have to add your employer's repository as a remote repository

```
git remote add [name] [url to repository]
```

You choose what name you want to provide, but `upstream` is a common choice. Now, to grab the changes, run

```
git pull upstream [branch]
```

Typically, you will be pulling the `master` branch. At this point, git will try to automatically merge the changes from your employer's repository with your working version. There may be some conflicts you will have to deal with. Once the merge is successful, and conflicts have been resolved (if any), you can push the changes to your forked repository

```
git push origin
```